# Construct a branch of $\sqrt{\log{z}}$ on the upper half-plane ${z\in C:Im(z)\geq0}$. Justify your answer

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

I can't quite figure out where I've gone wrong, my understanding is it should be something like:
$$\sqrt{\ln\vert z\vert+iArg(z)}$$ where $Arg(z)$ is the principle argument for z.

Comment: In what sense has it gone wrong?

Comment: You can end up with a negative under the root, where Arg(z) is $-\pi$ *i think*, and even if you restrict Arg(z) to the interval $[0,\pi]$, I can't figure out a way to restrict it to the upper half once you add the root.

Comment: You would only get a negative real under the root for real $z$ with $0 < z < 1$.

Comment: Something like $\frac{1}{2}+0i$ is possible though no? I can't find how to keep it to that branch after adding the root.
I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing, tried to find similar examples, but only ones without two operators came up.